# Edit a list to remove a defined variable and everything after and including a character

Tags: python, list, edit

I have the following set up:

```
variable = /XXX/XXX/XXX/
list = [/XXX/XXX/XXX/INFO_RANDOM_STRING_HERE.file, etc...]
```

I want to copy the list but trim the starting variable, and everything other than the "INFO" segment (i.e. everything after and including the _ before _RANDOM). The info is different every time, as is the RANDOM_STRING_HERE, but the variable is constant.

How can I achieve this?

To clarify, I have:

```
variable = /users/me/folder/
list = [/users/me/folder/file1_001_134543_X5_6MGFS.txt, /users/me/folder/file2_231_234233_Y5_6MGFFAS.txt, etc...]
```

And I want
list intact and a new list:

```
newlist = [file1, file2, etc...]
```

Comment: Please provide real data and a desired output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use **`split()`** inside a **`list comprehension`**:

```
[x.split(variable)[1].split('_')[0] for x in the_list]
```

See the full code:

```
variable = "/users/me/folder/"
the_list = ["/users/me/folder/file1_001_134543_X5_6MGFS.txt", "/users/me/folder/file2_231_234233_Y5_6MGFFAS.txt"]

print [x.split(variable)[1].split('_')[0] for x in the_list]
```

Outputs:

```
['file1', 'file2']
```

---

I have prepared another example (with comments) in case you don't want to use **`list comprehensions`** but a simple **`for`** loop:

```
variable = "/users/me/folder/"
the_list = ["/users/me/folder/file1_001_134543_X5_6MGFS.txt", "/users/me/folder/file2_231_234233_Y5_6MGFFAS.txt"]

results_list = list()

for full_path in the_list:
    _, file_name = full_path.split(variable) # This splits "/users/me/folder/file1_001_134543_X5_6MGFS.txt" into "/users/me/folder/" and "file1_001_134543_X5_6MGFS.txt" so we take the last one as 'file_name'
    file_name = file_name.split('_')[0]      # This splits e.g. "file1_001_134543_X5_6MGFS.txt" in ["file1", "001", "134543", "X5", "6MGFS.txt"] so we take only the first one, which is in index 0
    results_list.append(file_name)           # Adding e.g. "file1" to our 'results_list'

print results_list
```

Answer (score 1):

```
variable = "/users/me/folder/"
lst = ["/users/me/folder/file1_001_134543_X5_6MGFS.txt", "/users/me/folder/file2_231_234233_Y5_6MGFFAS.txt"]

lst[:] = [s.replace(variable,"").split("_",1)[0] for s in lst]

print(lst)
```

Output:

```
['file1', 'file2']
```

If you are actually just trying to get the basename you can do it with `os.path.basename`:

```
lst = ["/users/me/folder/file1_001_134543_X5_6MGFS.txt", "/users/me/folder/file2_231_234233_Y5_6MGFFAS.txt"]
from os import path
lst[:] = [path.basename(s).split("_",1)[0] for s in lst]


print(lst)
```

Output:

```
['file1', 'file2']
```

Answer (score 0):

```
variable = "/users/me/folder/"
list = ["/users/me/folder/file1_001_134543_X5_6MGFS.txt", "/users/me/folder/file2_231_234233_Y5_6MGFFAS.txt"]

length = len(variable)
list = [x[length:] for x in list]
```